# Is adding a subview to a view a retain cycle?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I need to know if this is a retain cycle. I ran this in leaks instruments and I did not get any leaks.

```
class myClass: UICollectionViewCell {
   var aView = UIView()

   func test() {
       self.addSubView(aView)
   }
}
```

Comment: I think no, it should not retain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code doesn't cause a retain cycle, but it doesn't work in practice either.

A view is required to be initialized with a (suitable) frame.

Comment: Is there a reason why it does not cause a retain cycle? I am confused about this.

Comment: A retain cycle occurs when two objects hold a strong reference to each other. In your example there's a strong reference from the superview to the subview but not the other way round

Comment: Views have a default frame of `{{0 ,0}, {0, 0}}`, which is valid, if mostly useless.

Comment: @Avi the sample code was just a sample. No worries. The real code is better written

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create retain cycles in Swift ( i hope just for study) you should always make present that a reference to an instance function means that you're referencing the instance as well. And when assigning to a variable, you're creating a strong reference. Make sure to wrap such references in a closure with a weak reference to the instance or make sure to manually set the variables to nil once you're done with them

Comment: thanks. i know this already. But for some odd reason, tonight, i sat at the screen and my mind just went blank. And didn't know why it wasn't causing a retain cycle. I have been coding too much. I understand again. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No it will not increase retain cycle

This Example will help you to get better idea

```
@interface TTParent : NSObject
 @property (atomic) NSMutableArray *children;
@end

@implementation TTParent

@end

@interface TTChild : NSObject

 @property (atomic) TTParent *parent;

@end

@implementation TTChild

@end
```

In Some Other Class

```
  TTParent *parent = [[TTParent alloc] init];
  parent.children = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     TTChild *child = [[TTChild alloc] init];
     child.parent = parent;
     [parent.children addObject:child];

 }
```

It will Increase Retail Cycle because both Parent and child has strong reference of each other

to avoid this

`@property (atomic,weak) TTParent *parent;`